# Recuperar otros datos de una consulta PHP en JS

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy realizando una galería y deseo recuperar el dato *src* de un juego de registros en una ventana modal.

Quiero exceptuar el método `GET` de PHP por *Id*.

El script solo muestra el resultado del primer registro.

```
<?php
    /* CARGA DE LOGOTIPO */
    <div class=" images item ">
        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" >
        <img id="imgal" src="../<?php echo $row_rsEmpresa ['carpeta']; ?>/fotos/mini-<?php echo $row_rsEmpresa ['img_logo']; ?>" alt="" />
        </a>
        <p> <?php echo $row_rsEmpresa ['img_logo']; ?> </p>
    </div>
    /* CARGA DE LOGOTIPO */
    ?>  
                        
    <?php 
    /* CARGA DE LAS FOTOGRAFIAS  */
    do 
    echo '
    <div class="images item " >
        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
        <img id="imgal2" src="../'.$row_rsEmpresa ['carpeta'].'/fotos_full/'.  $row_rsFotografias['imagen'].'" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <p>'.  $row_rsFotografias ['imagen'].'</p>
    </div>';
    while ($row_rsFotografias = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsFotografias));
    /* CARGA DE LAS FOTOGRAFIAS ASOCIADAS AL HOTEL */
    ?>

    <script>
        var srclogo = this.document.getElementById("imgal").src;  
        function logo()
        {
        document.write(srclogo);
        }    
            
        var imgsrc = this.document.getElementById("imgal2").src; 
        function imagen()
        {
        document.write(imgsrc);
        }
    </script>  

/*RECUPERAR LA RUTA DEL ARCHIVO en un Modal*/
<p class="mtop10"><strong>Nombre de Archivo:<script>imagen();</script></strong></p>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo estar pendiente de [este tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/609763/llenar-modal-con-datos-de-una-tabla-php-y-mysql)